# Are classes as LinkedList or HashSet considered dependencies?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dependencies

Recently I've heard about dependency injection and I'm very curious to know whether a class like **LinkedList** in Java or other Java native classes considered as dependency?

Let's say I would have a method in which I parse an array of strings to a set of strings.

Firstly, I make a collection object from an array - in this case it is linked list - and then I transform it into a HashSet.

So, are both HashSet and LinkedList considered as dependencies?

```
private Set<String> foo(String[] strs){
    LinkedList<String> listOfStrings = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(strs));
    Set<String> setOfStrings = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String s: listOfStrings){
        setOfStrings.add(s);
    }
    return setOfStrings;
}
```

Comment: They might be *technically* dependencies, but it is probably not worth the effort to worry about them as far as dependency injection, unless you foresee a scenario where you need to inject different container types into that method without altering its code.

Comment: The interesting dependencies are the ones you are likely to need to change in the future.

Comment: BTW You don't need a `LinkedList` in this example and you can use `Collections.addAll` instead of `Arrays.asLIst` You only need the collection you are returning and even this could be populated for you.

Comment: Technically if you are going to pass several values from external configuration file or system property to your application you can inject them as `Collection` or `Map`

Comment: @khelwood So, if I were to unit test this code the "dependencies" would not be even noticed and everything would be fine?

Comment: They are implementation details which could be changed or removed without the caller being any the wiser.

Comment: @Steve If I were unit testing this, I would only be looking at the input and the ouput, not about what happens inside the method.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ohhh, really, thanks! Will fix it.

Comment: @Steve I have added some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with khelwood -

Yes they are technically dependencies, but no, you don't need to worry about them from a dependency injection standpoint.

Dependency injection is used so that you can swap out the underlying class with a different one without changing the code in your method (often for unit testing).  In the case of "native java classes" the need to swap them is not usually needed so you usually don't need to use dependency injection for them.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, both HashSet and LinkedList are not exactly dependencies, since they are belonging to the 
internal implementation of the method here.

It could have been called DI, if you probably had a method which could have a Collection as an argument to which you could supply any type of collection as a dependency.

```
public void doSomeAction(Collection<String>) { // Here, any type of Collection can be supplied by the caller, essentially making it a dependency which you can inject for example during Unit Testing..

.......// some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to provide some dependency injection you could do the following.

```
static <T> Set<T> setOf(T... strs){
    return setWith(new HashSet<>(), strs);
}

// pass in the set to populate
static <T> Set<T> setWith(Set<T> set, T... strs) {
    Collections.addAll(set, strs);
    return set;
}
```

You could later do

```
// uses a sorted set
Set<String> words = setWith(new TreeSet<>(), "hello", "world");
```